# Could not find or load main class - Selenium webdriver java program

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium webdriver script that runs and works perfectly fine on eclipse. However, when I try to run it from the mac terminal, I keep getting errors.

I'm using this command to compile it on the terminal:

```
javac -cp ".:/Users/rkhalil/Downloads/selenium-2.48.2/selenium-java-2.48.2.jar:/Users/rkhalil/Desktop/selenium-2.48.2/selenium-java-2.48.2-srcs.jar:/Users/rkhalil/Desktop/selenium-2.48.2/libs/*" create_new_account.java
```

I get the following result:

> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

and when I try to run it using the following command:

```
java -cp ".:/Users/rkhalil/Downloads/selenium-2.48.2/selenium-java-2.48.2.jar:/Users/rkhalil/Desktop/selenium-2.48.2/selenium-java-2.48.2-srcs.jar:/Users/rkhalil/Desktop/selenium-2.48.2/libs/*" create_new_account
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "works perfectly fine on eclipse" mean? How are you running it from Eclipse?

Comment: @SiKing press the run button, and it executes the script

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be an easy answer.  When you say -cp ".", apparently the class your trying to run is either uncompiled or simply not in the location expected.  You can write a simple program to print out what is on the classpath:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        for(URL url: urls){
            System.out.println(url.getFile());
        }
```

But, to make it easier on yourself, I would suggest using [Gradle](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/) to build and organize your project.